# Finding Element By Property/Attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Given the following

```
  ...
     <tr xyz="Alpha"> ... </tr>
     <tr xyz="Bravo"> ... </tr>
     <tr xyz="Delta"> ... </tr>
  ...
```

how can I get the row having xyz = "Bravo" in JScript, 
aside from just creating a `getElementsByTagName()` loop, 
and testing each returned element for it?

Is `xyz` an attribute, or a property?

Comment: Attributes are settings that go on the element in html. Properties are settings which are associated with the element in the javascript language.

Comment: Upon inspecting, for a TR that has an onclick and this addition (xyz=""), the IE debugger lists 'xyz' as an attribute, specifically (with obj being a reference to the row) obj.attributes[1].

Comment: `xyz` is on the element itself, so it is an attribute (and also available to the native API using `getAttribute`.

Comment: So is there a way, similar to getElementById(), to get an element whose "xyz" attribute has a specific value?

Comment: Yes, Amit provides that in his answer.

Answer (score 6):

No `xyz` isn't a valid attribute or property, but data attributes introduced in HTML5 are valid .

You can use them like this:

```
     <tr data-xyz="Alpha"> ... </tr>
     <tr data-xyz="Bravo"> ... </tr>
     <tr data-xyz="Delta"> ... </tr>
```

Then you can use `.querySelector()` to find a particular element.

```
document.querySelector('[data-xyz="Bravo"]');
```

If you want to limit searching to tr alone, then do this:

```
document.querySelector('tr[data-xyz="Bravo"]');
```